# Let $S$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Show $S$ is a subset of its convex hull

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$ and $(y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots) \in S.$ Then $a(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) + b(y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots)$ in the convex hull of $S$ where $a, b \in [0, 1]$ and $a + b = 1.$ Let $a = 1, b = 0.$ Then $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$ in the convex hull of $S$.

Do you agree?

Comment: Yep, looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. (There is a minimum of 30 characters)

Comment: Apparently I gotta wait 6 minutes.

Comment: Six minutes for what?

Comment: Yes.Other equivalent def'ns of the convex hull of S are the intersection of all convex sets that have S as a subset, or the subset-smallest convex set that has S as a subset.